# Convert String in to time format

Tags: java, android, android-studio

i want to set a time for alarm .but when i get time value from db it is in string format .so tell me what i can do for this .
i am new here and in android plz ignore any mistake
the code is

```
String s= names.get(i).getTime();
System.out.println("Value: " + s);
//value of s is 11:50 AM
Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), AlarmReceiver.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent =PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(),     
RQS_1, intent, 0);
AlarmManager alarmManager=(AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);    
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, s.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
```

Comment: in the last line s.getTimeInMillis() recieves the error here

Answer (score 2):

Do this you can convert string to timeinMillis:

```
String givenDateString =s;
            Log.d("Pana", "The value of s is " + s);
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm", Locale.ENGLISH);
            sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+0530"));
            try {
                Date mDate = sdf.parse(givenDateString);
                timeInMilliseconds = mDate.getTime();
                Log.d("Pana ", "Date in milli :: " + timeInMilliseconds);

                Log.i("TAG", "System.currentTimeMillis() = " + System.currentTimeMillis());
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: java.text.ParseException gives me this

Comment: you have to change the format in SimpleDateFormat as per your code.

Answer (score 1):

```
String s= names.get(i).getTime();
System.out.println("Value: " + s);
//value of s is 11:50 AM
```

Printed value is in "hh:mm a" format.

So you should write as

```
Date d = new Date();
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");
d = df.parse(s);

Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), AlarmReceiver.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent =PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(),     
RQS_1, intent, 0);
AlarmManager alarmManager(AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);    
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, d.getTime(), pendingIntent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
Date m_date = new Date();
SimpleDateFormat m_dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");
m_date = m_dateFormat.parse(s);
m_date.getTime();
```

I checked below code & it is working fine on my side

```
        Date m_date = new Date();
        SimpleDateFormat m_dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");
        try
        {
            m_date = m_dateFormat.parse("11:50 AM");
        }
        catch (ParseException p_e)
        {
            p_e.printStackTrace();
        }
        m_date.getTime();
```

Comment: it gives me pasrse exception .java.text.ParseException when i put m_date = m_dateFormat.parse(s);

Comment: can you please check String s value. I put code with reference value in your question like "11:50 AM"

Comment: Now i put this .but same problem                                                                 String s = "11:50 AM";
            Date d = new Date();
            SimpleDateFormat hello = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");
            d = hello.parse(s);